# How to allow all SVG elements and its attributes using Antisamy?

Tags: java, html, security, xss, antisamy

I want to allow all the svg elements and its attributes using Antisamy. How do I do that? I tried including all the elements and its attributes in the Antisamy policy file, and setting the regular expression to allow any string as .* . But I get the following error messages

```
The svg tag contained an attribute that we could not process. 
The xmlns attribute had a value of "&#92;&#34;http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;w3&#46;org&#47;2000&#47;svg&#92;&#34;". 
This value could not be accepted for security reasons. We have chosen to remove this attribute from the tag and leave everything else in place so that we could process the input.

The width attribute had a value of "&#92;&#34;593&#92;&#34;". This value could not be accepted for security reasons.
```

And many other error messages for other tags as well. Is there any way I can allow these tags without adding all of them in the policy file?

Any help regarding this will be appreciated. Thanks!